# MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avplayer

I've been trying to get iOS's audio tap processors working with the iPod library without much luck.

The primary problems appear to be that sometimes the "Process callback" doesn't get called at all (Though the Prepare callback IS called).

When the PRocess callback DOES start getting called then things seems to work perfectly up until I pause the audio.  When I try to un-pause the audio then MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio fails (error: 268451843 and 268435459) and after that nothing happens.

When I try using it with a wave file stored in my documents directory then it works perfectly, Process is always called and pausing/unpausing works perfectly.

As I am writing a spectrum analysis app I thought perhaps extracting the audio data for spectrum analysis was taking too long (especially as for legacy reasons I am converting the incoming audio from float multi-channel to short single channel).  To try to combat this I tried to use a dispatch_async to pass buffered data across to the main thread for spectrum generation.  Again this seems to work reasonably well for wave files in my documents directory but fails completely for files form the iPod library.

Alas the whole audio tap stuff is woefully under documented and near impossible to debug due to the real-time nature of the callback.

Any advice or ideas would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get to any conclusion with this? I happen to have hit the same wall.

Comment: @pevasquez: Nope I abandoned it in the end and did it with AVAssetReader :(

Answer (score -1):

> Again this seems to work reasonably well for wave files in my
>   documents directory but fails completely for files form the iPod
>   library.

To read samples from files in the iPod library, you have to first import the files to a temporary folder. I have successfully used [this library](https://bitbucket.org/artgillespie/tslibraryimport), for importing.

Comment: Not quite the whole point of the Tap processor was to allow you to intercept audio playing through an AVPlayer directly from the ipod library ...